# Is a complex operator $T$ with $\langle T(v),v \rangle =0$ for all $v$ equal to $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V,\langle \cdot , \cdot\rangle)$ inner product space on $\mathbb{C}$ and let $T:V \rightarrow V$ prof or disproof. if $\forall v \in V$ $\langle T(v),v\rangle$  $ = 0$ than $T=0$.

I had found very easily counterexample for the case $F= \mathbb{R}$ by defending symmetric matrix that defines the inner product and the same matrix don't work on the complex filed than I thinking that it may be true.

the example for $F= \mathbb {R}$ :

$T(x,y) = (y,y) $ and $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$\langle u,v \rangle = u^T A v$

Comment: indeed I don't found it! thank you